# converting a text file with tags in a pandas dataframe with tags as fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file with this structure:

```
- ASDF : |a=1|b=1|c=1|d=1
- QWER : |b=2|e=2|f=2
- ZXCV : |a=3|c=3|e=3|f=3|g=3
- TREW : |a=4|b=4|g=4
```

and I'd like to create a dataframe like this:

| index | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASDF | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| QWER | NaN | 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 2 | NaN |
| ZXCV | 3 | NaN | 3 | NaN | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| TREW | 4 | 4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 4 |

which solution could I implement? consider that I don't know in advance how many rows I have, nor the number or name of the tags.
thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) first, then convert first column to `index` and split by `|` by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), split by `=`, convert index to columns and  pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), last create uppercase columns names:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', sep=':', header=None)


df1 = (df.set_index(0)[1]
         .str.split('|', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .str.split('=', expand=True)
         .dropna()
         .rename_axis(['a','b'])
         .reset_index()
         .pivot('a',0,1)
         .rename(columns=str.upper, index = lambda x: x.strip(' -'))
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
         
print (df1)
        A    B    C    D    E    F    G
ASDF    1    1    1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN
QWER  NaN    2  NaN  NaN    2    2  NaN
TREW    4    4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    4
ZXCV    3  NaN    3  NaN    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to load the data, then [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to fix the index name (removing the `-` ). [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to get the `key=value` pairs, and reshape with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
# using io.StringIO for the example
# in real-life use your file as input
import io
data = '''- ASDF : |a=1|b=1|c=1|d=1
- QWER : |b=2|e=2|f=2
- ZXCV : |a=3|c=3|e=3|f=3|g=3
- TREW : |a=4|b=4|g=4'''

# in real-life use:
#    (pd.read_csv('filename.txt',    sep=' : ', header=None,
df = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' : ', header=None,
                  names=['index', 'val'], engine='python')
        # cleanup index column
        .assign(index=lambda d: d['index'].replace('^-\s*', '', regex=True))
        # extract the key=val pairs and reshape
        # then merge to original
        .pipe(lambda d: d.join(d.pop('val')
                                .str.extractall('(\w+)=(\d+)')
                                .droplevel('match')
                                .set_index(0, append=True)
                                [1].unstack(0)
                              )
             )
     )
```

Alternative with a python dictionary comprehension (if your format is **strictly what you showed**):

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    df = (pd.DataFrame
            .from_dict({k[2:]: dict(x.split('=') for x in v[1:].split('|'))
                        for l in f if l.strip()
                        for k,v in [l.strip().split(' : ', 1)]},
                       orient='index')
            .reset_index()
          )
```

output:

```
  index    a    b    c    d    e    f    g
0  ASDF    1    1    1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  QWER  NaN    2  NaN  NaN    2    2  NaN
2  ZXCV    3  NaN    3  NaN    3    3    3
3  TREW    4    4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness regular expression for that following way

```
import re
import pandas as pd
text = '''ASDF : |a=1|b=1|c=1|d=1
QWER : |b=2|e=2|f=2
ZXCV : |a=3|c=3|e=3|f=3|g=3
TREW : |a=4|b=4|g=4'''
def extract_data(line):
    name = line.split()[0]  # name is everything before first whitespace
    data = dict(re.findall(r'([a-z]+)=(\d+)',line))
    return {"name":name,**data}
df = pd.DataFrame(map(extract_data,text.splitlines()))
df.set_index("name",inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output

```
        a    b    c    d    e    f    g
name
ASDF    1    1    1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN
QWER  NaN    2  NaN  NaN    2    2  NaN
ZXCV    3  NaN    3  NaN    3    3    3
TREW    4    4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    4
```

Explanation: I use regular expression with capturing group to find pairs of one-or-more lowercase ASCII characters `[a-z]+` and one-or-more digits `\d+` sheared by requal sign `=`, then conver that into `dict` and do build dict from that and `name`. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes every name appears no more than once in each line.